# Пунктуация предложений при использовании вставной конструкции/приложения

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире

Интересует пунктуация в похожих предложениях с использованием приложения (1) и вставной конструкции (2).

1. "Рука, державшая бянь - металлический хлыст, взметнулась вверх, но спокойный голос правителя остановил слугу". Если "металлический хлыст" в роли приложения, правильна ли пунктуация?
2. "Рука, державшая бянь (,) - это что-то вроде металлического хлыста (,) - взметнулась вверх, но спокойный голос правителя остановил слугу". Если "это что-то вроде металлического хлыста" выступает в роли вставной конструкции, нужна ли запятая перед первым и/или вторым тире? Знаю, что запятая перед первым тире может закрывать предшествующую придаточную часть; работает ли это с причастными/деепричастными оборотами, как в моем случае?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1. Вместо вступления**

Отвечаю преимущественно **для автора вопроса**, так как мне нравится этот пример.  Мне кажется,  что вы умеете  думать, сравнивать,  анализировать, а также у вас  есть желание понять суть вещей, а не только  ознакомиться с правилами.

Тема вашего вопроса **одна из самых трудных**, над ней еще предстоит долгая работа.  В правилах мы видим **описательный материал**, но там нет пока анализа, обобщения, систематизации. А я уже говорила, что разобраться в этой теме  можно, только соединив семантику, грамматику, интонацию и знаки препинания. Вот давайте **попробуем это сделать на частном примере.**

**2. Ответ на вопрос**

**Предложение 1**

*Рука, державшая бянь  **– это что-то вроде металлического хлыста, –** взметнулась вверх, но спокойный голос правителя остановил слугу.*

Здесь двумя тире обособляется вставка, поясняющая слово «бянь»  внутри причастного оборота, поэтому первой запятой нет. Вторая запятая закрывает причастный оборот.

**Предложение 2**

Здесь мы обособляем **приложение**, поэтому рассмотрим варианты **с одним и двумя** тире.

*(1) Рука, державшая бянь **– металлический хлыст**,  взметнулась вверх, но спокойный голос правителя остановил слугу.*

Если мы ставим одно тире, то должны **вписать приложение** в существующую структурно-интонационную схему, то есть приложение должно войти  в обособленное определение, однако  в одну фразу **это сложно прочитать.**

Посмотрим, **существуют ли вообще примеры**  с обособленными оборотами, к которым относится приложение.  Вот пример из ПАС:  *Проходя вдоль своего вагона **— нашего временного жилИща**,  увидели мы в окне знакомую физиономию* (тире поглощается запятой, отделяющей деепричастный оборот).

Мы видим, что в **деепричастный** оборот приложение  **встраивается** без труда,  на него даже ставится ударение в конце оборота.  А вот **причастный** оборот – он сам по себе уже **обособленная конструкция со вставочной интонацией**, поэтому приложение, как я думаю, придется  перенести на второй план речи, то есть оформить **как обычную вставку** с двумя тире:

(2) *Рука, державшая бянь **– металлический хлыст, –** взметнулась вверх, но спокойный голос правителя остановил слугу.*

**Как проверить решение?** Я пыталась найти подобные примеры, где приложение относится к обособленному причастному обороту и отделяется одним или двумя тире, но мне не встретилось ничего похожего.  Возможно, такой вариант применяется редко, так как выглядит он не очень симпатично.

Однако интересно, что такая  м о д е л ь  оформления применятся у Розенталя для обособления двух приложений: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=111#pp111  Примечание (п. 6)  если приложение поясняет другое приложение: *Все мы, воспитатели — **учителя  и родители**, — должны учитывать возрастные особенности в общении с детьми.*
В этом случае к уже обособленному запятыми **первому** приложению  добавлено **второе** приложение, обособленное **тире**.

**ВЫВОД.**  Если считать, что это решение верно, то мы видим следующее.  **Приложение** можно вписать **не в каждую конструкцию** только потому, что это приложение. Аналогично можно предположить, что  существуют обороты речи, которые **можно вписать в предложение и обособить одним тире**, но при этом  оборот не является приложением  (такой пример рассматривался недавно).

Comment: В школе учат, что с помощью тире обычно обособляется распространенное приложение, стоящее в конце предложения. Там и интонация соответствующая. Трудно вписать ту же интонацию в середину предложения.

Comment: С школьной темой всё ясно, но там вы изучаете базовые варианты,  а  в литературе разные конструкции встречаются, с ними-то обычно и бывают проблемы. Общий смысл моих вопросов в том, что одни и те же грамматические модели с одинаковой интонацией и пунктуацией  могли бы использоваться  как для приложений, так и для вставных конструкций. Тогда автор мог бы выбрать подходящий для себя вариант.